# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable in nested select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods, iqueryable

I wrote an extension method to get only approved absences out of a list of absences:

```
public static IQueryable<tblAbwesenheit> OnlyApprovedAbsences(this IQueryable<tblAbwesenheit> source)
{
    return source.Where(a =>
        (a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.Any() && a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.All(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID == AbsenceStatusIds.Approved))
        && (!a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any() || a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID != AbsenceStatusIds.Approved)));
}
```

When I'm using this method with a "normal" Select, everything is fine:

```
context.tblAbwesenheits.OnlyApprovedAbsences().ToList()
```

However when I'm using it inside a Select statement, I get an error:

```
context.tblMitarbeiters.Select(m => new
{
    Employee = m,
    AbsencesForEmployee = m.tblAbwesenheits.OnlyApprovedAbsences()
})
.ToList();
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.tblAbwesenheit]
>   OnlyApprovedAbsences(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.tblAbwesenheit])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have searched quite a lot, but could not find a way to teach Entity Framework to recognize my Method without expanding the query to

```
context.tblMitarbeiters.Select(m => new
{
    Employee = m,
    AbsencesForEmployee = m.tblAbwesenheits
        .Where(a =>
            (a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.Any() && a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.All(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID == AbsenceStatusIds.Approved))
            && (!a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any() || a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID != AbsenceStatusIds.Approved)))
})
.ToList();
```

Is there a way to get EF to recognize my Method?

Answer (score 2):

EF is trying to look for a SQL equivalent of your method and not finding one. It can find an equivalent of the expanded query, which is why that works.

You might be able to create an expression rather than a method

```
var OnlyApprovedAbsencesExpression = (a =>
            (a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.Any() && a.tblAbwesenheitsantraggenehmigungs.All(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID == AbsenceStatusIds.Approved))
            && (!a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any() || a.tblAbwesenheitsstornierunggenehmigungs.Any(g => g.AbwesenheitsgenehmigungsstatusID != AbsenceStatusIds.Approved)))
```

and then write something like

```
AbsencesForEmployee = m.tblAbwesenheits.Where(OnlyApprovedAbsencesExpression)
```

Comment: This gives me a compiler error: Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: If you explicitly type out the var as `Expression<Func<tblAbwesenheit, bool>>` it is working. However I'm still looking for a Solution without the `Where`